# Fazer script que está em JavaScript para Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

estou com a seguinte função em JavaScript:

```
function main() {
let data = fazGet("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all");
let moedaJSON = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(moedaJSON)
const keys = Object.keys(moedaJSON)
keys.forEach(key => {
     document.getElementById("Nome1").innerHTML += moedaJSON[key]["name"] + "<br>";
     document.getElementById("Alta1").innerHTML += moedaJSON[key]["high"] + "<br>";
     document.getElementById("Baixa1").innerHTML += moedaJSON[key]["low"] + "<br>";
     document.getElementById("Compra1").innerHTML += moedaJSON[key]["bid"] + "<br>";
     document.getElementById("Venda1").innerHTML += moedaJSON[key]["ask"] + "<br>";
})
```

Quero fazer a mesma coisa em Python, porém, a variavel "key" ela tem diferentes nomes. Ela é referente a um iten de um dicionario da API que irei colocar logo abaixo.

```
moedas = {
"USD": {
    "code": "USD",
    "codein": "BRL",
    "name": "Dólar Americano/Real Brasileiro",
    "high": "5.6769",
    "low": "5.6142",
    "varBid": "0.0038",
    "pctChange": "0.07",
    "bid": "5.6191",
    "ask": "5.6208",
    "timestamp": "1618585377",
    "create_date": "2021-04-16 12:02:59"
},
"DOGE": {
    "code": "DOGE",
    "codein": "BRL",
    "name": "Dogecoin/Real Brasileiro",
    "high": "2.36",
    "low": "0.733879",
    "varBid": "1.43577199",
    "pctChange": "192.92",
    "bid": "2.18",
    "ask": "2.18",
    "timestamp": "1618584926",
    "create_date": "2021-04-16 11:55:27"
}}
```

OBS: Esse dicionario acima ele é o mesmo deste link, só botei uma parte dele como exemplo e para não ficar algo grande. [Link aqui](https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all)

No Json como podem ver, temos "USD", "DOGE", etc... Como faço para que esses nomes se tornem variaves para assim facilitar o codigo. Isso tudo depois vou colocar com django por isso essa necessidade de mudar o script.

Comment: Não há como converter o [DOM HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) para o python.

Comment: Não precisa ser o DOM, apenas o modo de pegar o valor da API. Tenho um dicionario dentro de outro dicionario, quero chamar os valores do segundo dicionario sem precisar ter que digitar o item do primeiro.

Comment: @AugustoVasques esta falando de DOM no navegador ou esta falando de DOM apenas?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, é o [*DOM HTML*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), conforme o link passado, pois o  MCVE do AP faz uso extensivo desse. Até agora estou sem entender a pergunta e muito menos a resposta, ambas não tem relação com o exemplo apresentado.

Comment: Do link que você enviou "O DOM foi projetado para ser independente de qualquer linguagem de programação específica" @AugustoVasques, estou com dificuldade de entender ainda o seu primeiro comentário

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, como ficaria essa linha `document.getElementById("Nome1").innerHTML += moedaJSON[key]["name"] + "<br>";` em python?

Comment: @AugustoVasques isso não é questão de DOM, é um recurso especifico da interface DOM em JavaScript, o problema é que o primeiro comentário deu a entender outra coisa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, qual é a pergunta *Fazer script que está em JavaScript para Python*. Não tenho como fazer pois o DOM usado pela função me impede a tradução.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não estou dizendo que a pergunta não esta confusa, só quero dizer que o primeiro comentário soa outra coisa, pois não foi "dom" usado (DOM é o "modelo"), e sim a "API DOM" que não existe algo exatamente igual, apesar de poder ser compensado de outras formas, mas agora pelo seu ultimo comentário já deu para entender que você se refere API disso e não ao DOM de fato.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, correto. Entendi o que minha falha foi quanto a terminologia escolhida e utilizada. Obrigado pela correção, vou me esforçar para escolher melhor a terminologia e não ser ambíguo ao comentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi corretamente mas sua dúvida é como chegar nos valores mais interno do dicionário ?

Se for isso, é o código abaixo, eu faço um for em cima da variavel que trás a chave e o valor e um for interno em cima do valor que também é um dicionário, veja que não precisei especificar o nome da chave do dicionário.

```
import requests

moedas = {
"USD": {
    "code": "USD",
    "codein": "BRL",
    "name": "Dólar Americano/Real Brasileiro",
    "high": "5.6769",
    "low": "5.6142",
    "varBid": "0.0038",
    "pctChange": "0.07",
    "bid": "5.6191",
    "ask": "5.6208",
    "timestamp": "1618585377",
    "create_date": "2021-04-16 12:02:59"
},
"DOGE": {
    "code": "DOGE",
    "codein": "BRL",
    "name": "Dogecoin/Real Brasileiro",
    "high": "2.36",
    "low": "0.733879",
    "varBid": "1.43577199",
    "pctChange": "192.92",
    "bid": "2.18",
    "ask": "2.18",
    "timestamp": "1618584926",
    "create_date": "2021-04-16 11:55:27"
}}

#Lendo de uma página
r = requests.get('https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all')
#Pegar de uma Página http
#moedas = r.json()

for chaveMaster, valorMaster in moedas.items():
    print(f'Chaves Master: {chaveMaster}')
    for chave, valor in valorMaster.items():
        print(f'   Chave: {chave} - Valor: {valor}')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: opa, de nada...